# How to use double `sudo` in Ansible without password for `root` access?

Tags: ansible, centos7

I login to server (CentOS 7) as my user and execute double `sudo` to become `root`. No password is required at such times.

**Command**

```
sudo sudo su
```

I need to install applications on such server as `root` user using Ansible.

Unfortunately, when I try following

```yaml
---
- name: Copy file
  hosts: all

  become: true
  become_method: su

  tasks:

   - name: Copy file
     copy:
      src: abc.txt
      dest: /tmp/
```

it gives

```yaml
"msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt:"
```

I have tried other versions like changing `become_method` to `sudo`, etc. But they don't work.

Any suggestion which could help?

Comment: `become_method` should be `sudo` in your case. Why do you use `sudo sudo su`?

Comment: @JGK I have already tried become_method sudo. It doesn't work. It failes with message : "Sorry, user newuser is not allowed to execute'/bin/sh -c echo BECOME-SUCCESS-hsfakbuyohjnwftirxccgsalmvuegult". Server is configured in way to use double sudo. You can have idea through: https://superuser.com/questions/772428/why-does-a-double-sudo-modify-permissions

Comment: I think `sudo sudo su` won't work with ansible. Why don't you add a line to `/etc/sudoers` on the target machine like `your_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` and then everything is fine?

Comment: @JGK Thanks was able to do with update in /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 0):

> ***How to use double `sudo` in Ansible?***

**(1)**

According the [Become directives](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-directives) one could simply use `become_flags`.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_flags: 'sudo'
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: pstree
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
```

will result into an output of

```
ansible-playboo-+-ansible-playboo---sh---sudo---sudo---sh---python2---pstree
                `-{ansible-playboo}
```

Without the flag it would be a single `sudo`

```
ansible-playboo-+-ansible-playboo---sh---sudo---sh---python2---pstree
                `-{ansible-playboo}
```

**(2)**

You could create your own [Customized `become` Plugin](https://serverfault.com/a/1110414/448950).

**Similar Q&A**

- [Running Ansible tasks within a network namespace](https://serverfault.com/a/1110414/448950)

---

> ***Ansible without password for `root` access?***

**(3)**

As **already mentioned and confirmed within the comments**, this is nothing related to Ansible itself, but to [Managing `sudo` access](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-sudo-access_configuring-basic-system-settings). It is quite simple to resolve by configuring `sudoers`.

It assumed that the user `ansible_user` it either member of the local group `wheel` or has his its own `sudoers` entry within one of the file(s)

**`/etc/sudoers`**

```bash
%wheel                                ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
ansible_user                          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or **`/etc/sudoers.d/ansible_user`**

```bash
ansible_user                          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: who; id; sudo id
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
```

executed via

```bash
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user 'ansible_user' --ask-pass who.yml
```

will result then into an output of

```yaml
ASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    cmd: who; id; sudo id
    delta: '0:00:00.110247'
    end: '2023-10-10 09:00:00.110247'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-10-10 09:00:00.000000'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: |-
      ansible_user pts/0        2023-10-10 09:00 (192.0.2.1)
      uid=123456789(ansible_user) gid=1234560513(domain users) groups=1234560513(domain users) <omitted>
      uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

In the shown example the user `ansible_user` doesn't exist local at all, there is no entry in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` or `/etc/shadow` since the system is connected and joined to a domain.

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible: How to run a script without `become: true` but `sudo`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77263732/6771046)
- [Ansible: How to run script that uses `sudo` in places without `become: true`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77263713/6771046)

Comment: The first solution does not work for me : 
`unsupported sudo arguments:['sudo']`