# Ansible: How to run a script without 'become: true' but 'sudo'?

Tags: ansible, sh, sudo, ansible-2.x

I am trying to run a script of [xrdp-installer](https://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=17994) which asks me to run it with not `sudo` user but it runs some commands with `sudo` in some lines, like
`sudo systemctl enable xrdp.service` and many others.

I want to run this script without `become: true` but allow `sudo` runnings in it.
My simple playbook task is like

```yaml
- name: Run script xrdp installer
  shell:
    cmd: ./xrdp-installer-1.4.2.sh
    chdir: ~/
```

That's why I see those error lines in the output.

```json
"stderr_lines": [
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "grep: /etc/pam.d/xrdp-sesman: No such file or directory",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper",
        "sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper"
    ],
```

And I don't know how to configure configure an askpass helper.

Any ideas on how can I run it without `become: true`?

Comment: I'm also curious how to do this

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing related to Ansible itself, but to [Managing `sudo` access](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-sudo-access_configuring-basic-system-settings). It is quite simple to resolve by configuring `sudoers`.

It assumed that the user `ansible_user` it either member of the local group `wheel` or has his its own `sudoers` entry within one of the file(s)

**`/etc/sudoers`**

```bash
%wheel                                ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
ansible_user                          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or **`/etc/sudoers.d/ansible_user`**

```bash
ansible_user                          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: who; id; sudo id
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
```

executed via

```bash
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user 'ansible_user' --ask-pass who.yml
```

will result then into an output of

```yaml
ASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    cmd: who; id; sudo id
    delta: '0:00:00.110247'
    end: '2023-10-10 09:00:00.110247'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-10-10 09:00:00.000000'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: |-
      ansible_user pts/0        2023-10-10 09:00 (192.0.2.1)
      uid=123456789(ansible_user) gid=1234560513(domain users) groups=1234560513(domain users) <omitted>
      uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

In the shown example the user `ansible_user` doesn't exist local at all, there is no entry in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` or `/etc/shadow` since the system is connected and joined to a domain.