# Ansible: How to run script that uses 'sudo' in places without 'become: true'?

Tags: linux, ansible, sudo

I'm trying to run a shell script installer for a program via Ansible.

The script makes some assumptions that is gets the login user for non-sudo commands and `root` user when needed via `sudo`.

However, in Ansible, I can only get that same script to do one of two things:

1. Run without `become: true` -> **Result:** the `sudo` parts of the script fail ("a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper")
2. Run with `become: true` -> **Result:** the non-sudo parts of the script break, using `root` as the user when I actually need them to use the login user

Is there any way to get Ansible to behave similarly to a typical shell here (only becoming `root` purely as needed when the script calls `sudo`)?

Comment: Related posts I found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74611724/ansible-how-to-run-a-script-without-become-true-but-sudo and https://www.reddit.com/r/ansible/comments/8ddykb/ansible_run_script_that_calls_sudo_inside/

Comment: Is this related to Ansible? How would you do it without ansible? Sane shell script installers have non-interactive options to install, doing sudo in the installer is not sane (does the installed program itself requires sudo?). Bottom line, you may consider notifying upstream/vendor and clarify with them that the installation script is problematic in batch non-interactive use.

Comment: To start with, this is definitely a very bad practice with ansible and you have chosen the wrong tool. Anyhow, if you really want to persist on that path, you can try to automate answering the sudo prompt with the [`expect` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) but that's ugly and I would never do that on a real production target.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned within the comments this is nothing related to Ansible itself, but to [Managing `sudo` access](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/de-de/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_basic_system_settings/managing-sudo-access_configuring-basic-system-settings). It is quite simple to resolve by configuring `sudoers`.

It assumed that the user `ansible_user` it either member of the local group `wheel` or has his its own `sudoers` entry within one of the file(s)

**`/etc/sudoers`**

```bash
%wheel                                ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
ansible_user                          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or **`/etc/sudoers.d/ansible_user`**

```bash
ansible_user                          ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - shell:
      cmd: who; id; sudo id
    register: result

  - debug:
      var: result
```

executed via

```bash
sshpass -p ${PASSWORD} ansible-playbook --user 'ansible_user' --ask-pass who.yml
```

will result then into an output of

```yaml
ASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  result:
    changed: true
    cmd: who; id; sudo id
    delta: '0:00:00.110247'
    end: '2023-10-10 09:00:00.110247'
    failed: false
    msg: ''
    rc: 0
    start: '2023-10-10 09:00:00.000000'
    stderr: ''
    stderr_lines: []
    stdout: |-
      ansible_user pts/0        2023-10-10 09:00 (192.0.2.1)
      uid=123456789(ansible_user) gid=1234560513(domain users) groups=1234560513(domain users) <omitted>
      uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
```

In the shown example the user `ansible_user` doesn't exist local at all, there is no entry in `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group` or `/etc/shadow` since the system is connected and joined to a domain.